# How to test if a process is poisson, if there are a lot of zeros

Tags: python, poisson-distribution, zero-inflation, exponential-distribution

I have foot traffic data for how many people entered a building for every hour, for several days.
This SOUNDS like it should follow a poisson process.

Problem:
I need to statistically confirm that my process is poisson, so that I can estimate utilization by looking at lambda (average arrival rate in time *t*) divided by service rate, *mu*.

Data Issue/Nuance:
The data is fairly sparse so there are a lot of zeros.

What I have:
I have the average number of arrivals per hour, i.e. lambda
I also have the inter-arrival time, and average inter-arrival time.

Where I'm stuck:
I'm not sure how to go from what I have now, to confirm this process is poisson.

I read in one article to do a chi-square, goodness of fit test of my inter-arrival times, and compare that with sampling from an exponential distribution with my lambda as the parameter. Especially given that my data has a lot of zeros I'm not really sure how to adapt.

Trying to do this in either Python or R

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by 'a process is Poisson'? Are you suggesting that the foot traffic is constant (e.g. during the night you have as much traffic as during the day) and that traffic is not clustered (people do not enter buildings in groups)?

Comment: So that's what I was trying to figure out, each person is treated independently. And during business hours the traffic can be fairly constant. But because of the hours late at night there are a lot of zeros in the data. I understand it's not a perfect fit for poisson but the prototypical example is usually a call center, which would have the same issue. Do you have any suggestions on if I can test if my data behaves like a poisson distribution?

Comment: You can use Pearson's chi-squared test to compare the observed distribution with some expected distribution. The main question seems to me 'what is your expected distribution?'. When you are comparing with a regular homogeneous Poisson process then you are obviously gonna fail, because you know there are discrepancies like inhomogeneous rates as function of time (and those create the zero's). Why do you need to know whether the process is Poisson? What is the point?

Comment: Yes, so that's the answer I'm trying to get to. I have a histogram (and the underlying data) of inter-arrival times, and it looks like a exponential distribution, but how can I create a theoretic exponential distribution to do the chi-squared test against, what value should I use in which function in either R or Python? Let's say foot traffic is 8.37 per hour. Can you please point me to how to use this information to confirm if my inter-arrivals follow an exponential distribution? I tried a couple of things with numpy, but the values I was getting were orders of magnitudes off...

Comment: True, and fair. I want to use this formula for Utilization from M/M/1 queueing theory: ρ = λ/μ, see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue, stationary analysis). But for this to be fairly used, my lambda process needs to be poisson. So I have data that I believe is poisson distributed, but I need to confirm that. My goal is to compare various locations via their utilization rate for what proportion of time a place is busy.

Comment: I am still a bit puzzled about what you are trying to achieve. Mostly, *why* you are trying to find out whether the process is Poisson. Depending on what you are gonna do with it the answer to the question will be different. It is a bit of an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and in statistics the underlying background can be very important for the strategy to solve the problem. There is not gonna be a single solution, and as George Box said 'all models are wrong but some are useful'. The problem here is to figure out what is useful for you, and that requires context.

Comment: Would it not be easier to tackle the applicability of the queuing theory directly? The question is not whether your process is Poisson (it will not be *exactly* Poisson in most practical situations, but does that really matter?) but whether you can use queuing theory with reasonable accuracy. Or actually, the question is about 'utilisation rate of different places'.

Comment: *"I read in one article to do a chi-square, goodness of fit test of my inter-arrival times, ... given that my data has a lot of zeros I'm not really sure how to adapt."* How to adapt depends on the situation (not just the fact that you have lots of zero's)

Comment: Well so I'd like to prove or disprove the applicability of queueing theory in this problem, ideally by using a chi-square test. But in my limited knowledge, I'm not sure how to proceed in the case when the arrival rate isn't constant because of off-hours. I can trim the data to remove off-hours, but then the issue becomes, what time does "day" start and "end", and if I'm just trimming my data to force it to behave one way then I think that'd be misleading too...

Comment: But what do you want to do with it? Why are you doing this? What is the profit that you might gain from this analysis? And how is *that profit* a function of you actions that may stem from the analysis? (I can imagine that you wish to reduce/increase service levels in some way in order to optimize the balance between cost of service and risk of having too large waiting lines)

Comment: Knowing the utilization, will allow me to compare the viability of different locations for certain services. But I don't want to make a comparison on the basis of a formula with a violating assumption....or do I? I mean realistically I can't think of many real-life examples that conform to the constant rate of arrival rules, and my professor used this type of analysis for Atlanta's international airport. Flights are round the clock but heaviest during the day of the airport's locale.

Comment: I think removing the off-peak hours and then stating that my utilization only represents on-hours would be fair, and over the on-hours my process is very close to real poisson, constant average rate of arrivals, independent. Thoughts?